# Handling multiple client sockets with SFML

Tags: c++, pointers, sfml, stdmap

I am currently trying to write the networking part of a little multiplayer game, and I am facing a problem to store my TCP sockets which are, in SFML, non-copyable (I am a beginner in C++).

I have three classes : `Server`, `Client` (a server-side class used to store all informations about a connecting client) and `ClientManager`, which is in charge of storing all clients and giving them IDs, etc.

**ClientManager.h**

```
    class ClientManager {
    public:
        ClientManager();
        std::map<int, Net::Client*> getClients();
        int attribID();
        void addClient(Net::Client *client);
        sf::TcpSocket getClientSocket(int id) throw(std::string);
        void setClientSocket(int id, sf::TcpSocket);
    private:
        std::map<int, Net::Client*> m_clients;
        std::map<int, sf::TcpSocket> m_clientSockets;
        std::vector<int> m_ids;
        int m_lastID;
};
```

What I planned to do originally, when a client connects, is :

```
void Net::Server::waitForClient() {
   while(true) {
    if(m_listener.accept(m_tcpSocket) != Socket::Done) {
        cout << "Error happened during client connection. skipping. " << endl;
        return;
    }
    int newID = m_clientManager.attribID();
    this->m_clientManager.addClient(new Net::Client(newID, m_tcpSocket, m_tcpSocket.getRemoteAddress()));
   }
}
```

So, adding a new `Client` into ClientManager's list, with its ID, a TcpSocket to send info and his address.

But, the problem is that SFML's TcpSocket class is not copyable, which means I can't copy it to a Client like this.

I could pass it as a pointer to the original TcpSocket, but what if another client connects ? The data the pointer points to will have change and the program will bug. I do not know if this behavior will be the same with smart pointers, but I think so (but I don't master them at all).

Storing them in a `std::map` or `std::vector` causes the same problem, as they both copy the object. Storing them as pointers (in the map) to the original TcpSocket will cause the same problem as before, because the socket will change too, and the pointers will point to the same object.

How can I store my sockets without having to use references, pointers or to copy my object ?

Any help will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: I will have to look more into this when I get home, but I believe you can pass the address of the socket to your clientManager, and then get the IP and port information from the socket and store that.

Comment: You could use dynamic memory, using a std::unique_ptr or shared_ptr, and just store the pointers in your vector/map (This would require you to allocate memory for each connection).

Comment: Hey and thanks for your answer ! It would indeed require to allocate memory for every new connected client (or we would meet the case of the pointers just). By allocating memory, do you mean : creating a `shared_ptr` pointer at the beginning of the while loop, allocating memory with `new` and then having a `std::map<int, std::shared_ptr<TcpSocket>>` (or any other way with another `shared_ptr`) to store them in `ClientManager` ?

Comment: yes that is what I mean.

Comment: If anybody has the same problem (i.e. storing SFML sockets), I found a nice example in their documentation here : https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1SocketSelector.php

Comment: The socket selector is NOT a container for sockets, and if you expect it to be you'll have many issues with your program.

Comment: I know this very well. The interesting thing with this example is that it also provides a way to store sockets, which I thought would not be working, but in fact does :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's going to be a real pain to do without pointers. Personally I use smart pointers to manage the sockets themselves (`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<sf::TcpSocket>>` or similiar), along with `sf::SocketSelector' to manage the actual communication

Comment: This is what I ended doing, as I suggested in my comment answering to Eddge, except that I used a `std::map` (as I need to have an ID too) and `std::shared_ptr` (which I do not know if it fits well my use case as I don't master smart pointers well, but at least works). I also ended using `sf::SocketSelector` too :)

Comment: I'd recommend using unique_ptr over shared_ptr where possible (plenty of internet arguments floating around about this, I won't bore you...), but I doubt it will cause you any problems. glad it's working :)

Comment: I'll take a (big) look later about this, it's part of the subjects I want to know more about :)

Comment: If you're using SFML a lot, the irc channel is full of (mostly helpful) weirdos with (and some without) SFML expertise , join us...

Comment: I'll have a go at it :)